# Comment on dit en français qu'un chien monte sur un homme ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

L'expression que je cherche décrit un chien qui vient « dire bonjour » et met ses deux pattes sur ma poitrine.

Je déteste ça parce que mon pull va être sale.

Comment puis-je dire :

> I don't think dogs should **jump up** on people

en français ?

Comment: « Monter » en français ne signifie pas autre chose que faire du cheval ; le reste c'est de l'ordure.

Comment: @LPH Que signifie votre commentaire ? Je ne le comprends pas. Monter a bien une pléthore de significations, non ? http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/monter

Comment: @Dimitris Quand on dit « monter » dans le sens figuré, et cela ne peut être que le sens figuré (élever la position de l'homme ? Non ), il n'y a qu'une possibilité essentiellement, c'est « monter un animal », ce qui veut seulement dire l'enfourcher et se faire porter (on l'emploie pour un cheval énormément mais on peut l'utiliser pour une mule, un âne ou même un autre animal). « Il montait un cheval marron. »  par exemple, signifie « il se déplaçait sur le dos d'un cheval marron. ». « Sur » est donc nécessaire dans le présent contexte, qui est assez littéral.

Answer (score 6):

Je dirais familièrement [grimper](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grimper/38266?q=grimper#38206) dans le sens de monter en s'agrippant. [S'agripper à](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_agripper/1783?q=s%20agripper#1788) fonctionnerait avec certaines formulations. Je ne conçois pas le geste comme un saut.

> Je ne pense pas qu'on devrait permettre aux chiens de grimper sur le
>   monde. [les gens]
>  Je n'aime pas me faire grimper dessus par un chien.
>   Je n'aime pas quand un chien me grimpe dessus.

Answer (score 5):

An idiomatic phrase for this: "**sauter sur (quelqu'un)**".

Note the difference: "**monter sur (quelque part)**".

> Comment empêcher que mon chien **saute sur**  les invités /  les gens / un autre chien ?
>
> {vs}: Comment empêcher que mon chien **monte sur** la table / le canapé ?

Answer (score 0):

Non locuteur natif. Je dirais :

> Je ne pense pas que les chiens devraient sauter sur les gens.

où

> should = conditionnel du verbe devoir dans ce contexte.
>
> jump up on = sauter sur

Answer (score -1):

Je ne connais pas de terme qui en un mot ou deux permette d'identifier cette position dans laquelle les chiens se mettent pour fêter un être humain mais elle peut être décrite sans trop de difficulté. Ils se campent sur leurs pattes arrières et prennent appui avec leurs pattes de devant sur votre poitrine (votre corps).

- Je pense que les chiens ne devraient pas se camper sur leurs pattes arrières et prendre appui sur votre corps avec celles de devant pour vous fêter.

Évidemment on pourrait utiliser simplement « monter sur » ou « monter dessus » suivant le contexte, mais ce n'est pas aussi précis bien dans la plupart des cas une personne d'éducation normale ne confondra pas avec le comportement de ces chiens qui affectent des simulacres de copulation contre les jambes des gens.

- Je pense que les chiens ne devraient pas monter sur les gens pour les fêter.
- Je n'aime pas que les chiens me montent dessus pour me fêter.

Comment: Quand il s'agit de mobilier on comprend que « monter dessus » ou « monter sur qqc » est littéral ; lorsqu'il s'agit des gens on comprend que c'est « s'appuyer », c'est aussi idiomatique ; de toute façon il n'y a pas le moindre saut dans ce comportement des chiens, mais « sauter sur » se dit aussi, c'est vrai.